# After adding browser-router, I am getting warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Trying to create a ReactNav using `create-react-app`, just the second after adding the browserRouter, I am getting the warning:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.

```
Module../src/index.js
src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from "./App";
   5 | import "./index.css";
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <BrowserRouter>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </BrowserRouter>,
```

This is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Nav from "./components/nav/nav";
import Home from "./components/home/home";
import About from "./components/about/about";
import Contact from "./components/contact/contact";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav />
          <div className="container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "jardinteresa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using two time BrowserRouter why?

Comment: check i posted improved code https://stackoverflow.com/a/58470552/6544460.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar yup, that was the issue, copy paste issue. thanks!

Comment: if it helped you, can you please vote for https://stackoverflow.com/a/58470552/6544460

Comment: @VahidAkhtar `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, )
```

Use this only because 2 times BrowserRouter you are using.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav />
          <div className="container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Remove BrowserRouter from

```
import App from "./App";

import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App /> ,)
```